# Auth0 upon laravel 5.8 unable to authenticate an endpoint: Auth0\Login\Auth0Service::__construct() must be of the type array, null given,

Tags: php, laravel, auth0, laravel-5.8

I try to authenticate an endpoint using the auth0 library on an existing laravel 5.8 application (I know I need a serious upgrade but ain't got time):

```
$ composer require auth0/login
$ php artisan vendor:publish --tag=auth0-config
```

And I made the following route:

```
Route::prefix('/test')->middleware(['auth0.authenticate'])->group(function(){
    Route::get("/hello",function(){
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be authenticated to see this.',
            'authorized' => Auth::check(),
            'user' => Auth::check() ? json_decode(json_encode((array) Auth::user(), JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR), true) : null,
        ], 200, [], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    });
});
```

Furthermore my `auth.php` is:

```
<?php

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'auth0',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver'   => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],


        'auth0' => [
            'driver' => 'auth0',
            'provider' => 'auth0',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => App\User::class,
        ],
        'auth0' => [
            'driver' => 'auth0',
            'repository' => \Auth0\Laravel\Auth\User\Repository::class
        ],
    ],
    
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table'    => 'password_resets',
            'expire'   => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

My settings are:

```
AUTH0_STRATEGY=api
# The URL of your Auth0 tenant domain
# You'll find this in your Auth0 Application's settings page.
AUTH0_DOMAIN=dev-XXXXXXX.eu.auth0.com

# Your Auth0 application's Client ID
# You'll find this in your Auth0 Application's settings page.
AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=XXXXXXXXX

# Your Auth0 Custom API identifier/audience.
# You'll find this in your Custom API's settings page.
AUTH0_AUDIENCE=https://etable.local/test/
```

As Api says. Then I perform the following request via curl:

```
curl --request POST \
 --url https://dev-gv9fxa52.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token \
 --header 'content-type: application/json' \
 --data '{"client_id":"XXXXXXX","client_secret":"XXXXXXXX",
 "audience":"https://etable.local/test/",
 "grant_type":"client_credentials"}'
```

And I perform the following request using insomnia:

```
GET https://api.local/test/hello
Authorization: Bearer ^bearer from api above^
```

But I get the following error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Auth0\Login\Auth0Service::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/api/vendor/auth0/login/src/Auth0/Login/LoginServiceProvider.php on line 68
```

Any ideas why Service provides it not initialised?

Answer (score 0):

you can check Auth0's interactive docs and follow step by step [here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/laravel/interactive)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).